# Java mySQL login with MD5 passwords issue

Tags: java, mysql, easyphp

I have the following issue : I can't login with my following code : 
I'm not getting any sintax error but I can't get the ' loginSuccess boolean to get true. Code and table pic lower :

I've even tried the equivalent of VB.NET query- type without any success :

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) From users1 WHERE username = @Username AND password = MD5(@Password); "
```

with

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = ('MD5(" + password + ")'");
```

OR

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = MD5("' + password + ")'");
```

[image]

```
String sqlQuery = "select count(*) > 0 as match_found FROM username WHERE username = ? and password = MD5(?)";
// String sqlQuery = "select count(*) > 0 as cnt FROM username WHERE username = ? and password = MD5(?)";

PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement( sqlQuery );
pst.setString( 1, username );
pst.setString( 2, password );

ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
boolean loginSuccess = false;
if( rs.next() ) {
  loginSuccess = rs.getBoolean( "match_found" );
  int cnt = rs.getInt(1);
  System.out.println(cnt);
}

if(loginSuccess)
    System.out.println("yess");
else
    System.out.println("noo");
```

Comment: id 3 row password isn't a md5 hash..

Comment: By the way, why use count and a condition in query to determine this? Just 'select *' could be enough and if rs.next(), it will mean user exists else not.

Comment: And what message do you get??

Comment: @MarcoAcierno - I did the 3'rd row on purpose to test out why my MD5 isn't working.
 
Actually the problem comes from my password, it's varchar was initially set to 10 char, not sufficient for a proper MD5 encryption. Thanks for the answers tho.

Comment: Got it all solved, I only had to modify the varchar from 10 to a bigger value (100) etc
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @ask-dev everything is better of `select *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came up from my password varchar, it was 10 and the encryption didn't had enough space. Raised it to 50/100 and now I can login.
Thanks

Comment: VARCHAR(32) should be ok too, anyway consider the idea to use SHA-1 or Whirlpool (i love it, but it's me)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am really interested into cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize this code , I tested it it works . I hope it helps other people also

```
try {
                 Connection conn;
                 String dbuser = "root";
                 String dbpassw = "12345";
                 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourdatabasename";
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbuser,dbpassw);
                   String username = jTextField2.getText();  // this is for user name textfield 

                   String password = new String (jPasswordField1.getPassword()); // this is for your paswordfield 

                   PreparedStatement rs = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users where username=?  and password=?");
                   rs.setString(1,username );
                   rs.setString(2,password );
                 ResultSet  pst = rs.executeQuery();
                  if(pst.next()){
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed ");
// do whatever you want if the login is successfull                        

                   }else {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Succesful");

                   }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(myLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(myLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```